# Закрывая доступ через htaccess, можно как то получить доступ по другому протоколу?

Tags: .htaccess

Сделал я папку Cache, где хранятся кешированые файлы (с конфигамии приватными и прочими кешироваными файлми), закрыл доступ через .htaccess в этой папке

```
deny from all
```

Все работает, доступа нет к этой папке и вложенным через адресную строку.

Но вот вопрос, можно как то обойти это, и получить доступ к этим файлам еслии знать прямой путь, не через адресную строку?...

Comment: изнутри сервера да, если у пользователя права есть, извне нет

Comment: Ответ полностью зависит от вашей конкретной конфигурации вашего конкретного сервера, может и можно